# sort uniq(@stuff) doesn't sort, doesn't de-dupe

Tags: perl, sorting

> Some code has me waxing lyrical,
>   The outcome is slightly hysterical.
>   `sort`ed output I seek,
>   All elements `uniq`ue,
>   But the results? Far from clinical.

#### Code in question

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub uniq { my %seen; grep ! $seen{$_}++, @_ }

my @test = ();
for ( 1 .. 3 ) {
  @test = sort uniq( @test, qw/ d d c c b b a a / );
  print "@test\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
d d c c b b a a
d d c c b b a a d d c c b b a a
d d c c b b a a d d c c b b a a d d c c b b a a
```

#### The Fix

An extra set of parentheses restores parity:

```
@test = sort( uniq( @test, qw/ d d c c b b a a / ) );  # a b c d
```

Running the two lines through `-MO=Deparse` sheds some light on the effect of the extra parens - it forces the interpreter to treat the RHS as `sort LIST` instead of `sort SUBNAME LIST`:

```
# Doesn't work as intended (sort SUBNAME LIST)
@test = (sort uniq @test, ('d', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'));

# Works as intended (sort LIST)
@test = sort(uniq(@test, ('d', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a')));
```

#### My Question

- **Why is the extra set of parentheses necessary?**

  `uniq` returns a list, so I'd expect

  ```
  sort uniq( @stuff );
  ```

  to be equivalent to

  ```
  sort LIST
  ```

Comment: Tested on both Perl 5.8.8 and 5.16.3

Answer (score 2):

Although it's rarely used, the first form listed in `perldoc -f sort` is `sort SUBNAME LIST`. i.e. the optional second argument to sort is the *name* of a function to use as the sort comparator. The `LIST`, of course, may or may not have parentheses as it wants, and whitespace is free, so

```
 sort uniq( @test, qw/ d d c c b b a a / )
```

means to sort the list `(@test, qw/ d d c c b b a a /)` with the function `uniq` as a comparator. Since the result of `uniq` is independent of `$a` and `$b` and it has no prototype, it always returns `undef`, which sort considers as 0, and sort responds to this assertion that everything is equal by not changing the order of anything (since it's a stable sort, since 5.8 at least).

Comment: To answer OP's question as to why the extra parens are necessary: `sort( ... )` is being interpreted as `sort` with a *single* parameter which is what OP wants.  Without the parens, Perl sees the multiple parameter version `sort SUBNAME LIST`.

Comment: The OP knows all that. They asked why it's being interpreted as `sort SUBNAME LIST` without the parens.

Comment: @ikegami you're replying to a months-old closed post.

Answer (score 1):

`uniq` treated as a sub name because it's an identifier or a qualified identifier that's not also a function name. No actual check is made to see if the sub actually exists (although it would have found the sub to exist in this case).

`sort` needs to be followed by a function name or something that's not an identifier or qualified identifier to be disqualified from the `sort SUBNAME LIST` syntax.

Comment: I figured that. But the question is why? I put parens around the arguments to `uniq` and it's supposed to return a list, right?

Comment: So you're asking why is `uniq` treated as a sub name? Well, it is one, isn't it?

Comment: @Zaid because there's "sort", the name of a sub, and then a list.

Comment: @ikegami - I get what you're saying.  Perl sees `uniq` as `SUBNAME` and `(@stuff)` as `LIST`, but why does `sort( uniq(@stuff) )` not parse the same way? (Which will more fully answer OP's question.)

Comment: I see, so you're saying that the post-`uniq` parens do nothing to change precedence of how the call is evaluated

Comment: @Mr. Llama, Probably so `sort( uniq(@stuff) )` does what you want!

Comment: @Zaid, No different than `@a = (@b);`